# Use img src as background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to use img src as background-image when media queries is in use.

My media queries is actived while max-width: 854px.

I'm trying it with jQuery but don't work.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 854) {
            $('a.class').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('a.class img').attr(src) + ')');
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript variable called `src`? If so, what is the value? If not, are you sure that shouldn't be quoted like `.attr('src')`?

Comment: @mason Follow up to mason's comment. Did you get an error? ALWAYS check your console

Comment: @mason Thank you! I forgot put src between quotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it with jQuery, you will probably want to do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 854) {
        $('a.class').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).children('img').attr('src') + ')');
        });
    }
});
```

I used an `each` loop because I guess you could have multiple `a.class` and I use quotes for the src attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$('a.class').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('a.class img').attr(src) + ')');
```

to

```
$('a.class').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('a.class img').attr('src') + ')');
```

The [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function expects a string. You needed to quote the value since `src` is the name of the attribute.

You probably would have caught this if you checked your browser's consoles for errors as [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes) suggested. Or if you looked at the syntax highlighting in your IDE you'd notice that `src` was colored like variable name instead of a string value.

Answer (score 0):

$('a.class').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('a.class img').attr("src") + ')');

"src" has to be between quotes.